# How to link a relationship in spring data without cascading data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data and have two entities with a OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship between eachother respectively. I want the relationship to function simply as a foreign key reference and nothing more however when I save contact data it also saves all data under Person and its relations which I do not want. I just want it to link the person entity to the contact entity and nothing more. I tried many things including different Cascade types and removing cascade alltogether.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public UUID person_id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    public List<Contact> contacts;

    ...etc

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public UUID contact_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    public Person person;

    ...etc

}
```

Comment: Can we see your dao / service layer code please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all cascading, just use CascadeType.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

Comment: I tried using various cascade types  such as Refresh detach and even no cascade type however the functionality did not change

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the code of saving your contact, I'm interested in how you do your data manipulation, maybe I can help you more if you will update the question :)

Answer (score 0):

When you save a contact data for a specific person record, that person record must already exist if you declare the domain objects as described in your question. So you are going to do like:

```
Person person = personRepository.findOne(personId);
contact.setPerson(person);
contactRepository.save(contact);
```

This simply creates a relationship (a foreign key), and adds the primary key of the specified person to the newly created contact record. Nothing is changed in the person record.

Comment: Yes the person record does exist. To add a bit more clarity the person record exists and has other relations. When I create contact I simply want to fetch the person from the database and link it to person but it seems to want to update those other relations even though data did not change.